# Cartesian diagrams and canonical isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory

The definition I read is that a commutative square - I'm sorry that I can't text it here - consisting of $Z\stackrel{u}{\rightarrow}X\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}S$ and $Z\stackrel{v}{\rightarrow}Y\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}S$ is called cartesian, if the induced morphism $Z\rightarrow X\times_SY$ is an isomorphism.

Question 1: Are there examples of spaces $Z$ that make the upper square commuative and are isomorpic to $X\times_SY$, but the canonical morphism $Z\rightarrow X\times_SY$ is not an isomorphism?

I would say that in my eyes this question is related to non-reflexive Banach-spaces that are isomorphic to their double-dual; in both cases we fail that a canonical morphism is an isomorphism, yet we still have an isomorphism.

Question 2: Is there a appropriate categorical notion/concept to deal with such "phenomena"?

Question 3: This is rather a philosophical question, but is it somewhat correct to say that "If the canonical map is no isomorphism, the chance that we have an isomorphism is very low"?

Comment: Replace "nope" by "This is an interesting idea. However, I doubt that there is a connection between this fact and your question."

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If there is no connection at all, why did I think of it while typing my inital question? After all, I deliberately used the phrase "in my eyes" and never stated it as a truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually happens a lot. For example, when $S$ is a terminal object, $X\times_S Y$ is just the product $X\times Y$, and any square
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
Z @>>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
Y @>>> S
\end{CD}$$
automatically commutes.

Now take $Z=X\times_S Y$, and let $h\colon Z\to Z$ be any map which is not an isomorphism. Let $f=\pi_1\circ h$ and $g=\pi_2\circ h$. Then the diagram
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
Z @>f>> X \\
@VgVV @VVV \\
Y @>>> S
\end{CD}$$
commutes and the canonical map $(f,g)\colon Z\to X\times_S Y$ is $h$, which is not an isomorphism.